# Gtk vim remove mapping of <C-Y>

Tags: vim, settings

I used classic vim, but recently i moved to gtk-vim on ubuntu, but emmet plugin don't working, it is because when I press `<C-Y>` it copies above char to cursor position, i failed to disable it. When i set unmap or iunmap `<C-Y>` it writes that there is no maping, also this shortcut is not noted in imap.

EDIT:
I find out that i'm unable to imap, when i press any shortcut it just print it out, for instance

```
map <F2> :echo 'Current time is ' . strftime('%c')<CR>
```

is working well but

```
imap <F2> :echo 'Current time is ' . strftime('%c')<CR>
```

is printing `<F2>` to text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've `:set paste`, which disables insert mode mappings and abbreviations. This option is meant for pasting text from the terminal (e.g. via middle mouse button); it should only be set *during* the paste itself, not permanently (and you can easily toggle this via the `'pastetoggle'` option).

So, check via `:verbose set paste?`, then find the place where this is set, and disable it.

---

PS: Your demo imap needs `<C-o>` before it; else (if imaps are working, that is), you'd just insert the `:echo ...` into the buffer.

```
imap <F2> <C-o>:echo 'Current time is ' . strftime('%c')<CR>
```